# c global variables in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i would like to do some order to my self about the globals.

1. if i write in my .m file

   ```
   int ran //is it global? every class can see it ?

   @implementation
   @end
   ```
2. if i am writing in my .h file this:

   ```
   int ran //is it global to any other class that include this .h ?
   @interface
   {
   }
   ```
3. if i am writing in my .h file this:

   ```
   extern int ran //is it global to any other class that include this .h ?
   @interface
   {
   }
   ```
4. if i am writing in my .h file this:

   ```
   @interface
   {
   int ran //can every other class that include it can see it ?
   }
   ```

   `AND` about the `@interface`, every thing that in the interface is belong to that class only?
   what about `*NSString` that in the @interface? is it belong to that class only ? 
   can i use it when including this .h? or do i have to make an **object** of that class to see it ?

What is the best way to put a global variable of a primitive , that only my class will see it and can be use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you write (in any compilation unit == .m file)

   ```
   int ran;
   ```

   Fine, **defines** a global variable, initialized to zero, symbol visible to the linker.
2. If you write in a header file

   ```
   int ran;
   ```

   That's a bad idea, since every implementation file (.m) that includes the header would define it's own instance of the global variable. Linker confusion would arise.
3. If you write in a header file

   ```
   extern int ran;
   ```

   Fine, **declares** a global variable. Must be defined in **one** implementation file (.m).
4. If you write in a header file

   ```
   @interface Foo : NSObject
   {
       int ran;
   }
   ```

   That's ok, too. It declares an Objective-C class with an instance variable `ran`. The instance variable would be created for and belong to each instance of `Foo`. The instance variable is @protected (by default) and can thus be accessed directly from any deriving class. This would be bad design, though.

   Nowadays you would not declare instance variables in the `@interface` of a class but in the `@implementation` or just `@synthesize`them.

If you need a private global variable, define it in you implementation file using:

```
static int ran;
```

Comment: thank you all. so in other words, if i need a global to be known outside a class i do "extern" and if i need a variable to be global INSIDE the class ONLY i do "static" int ?  because people warned me about putting a static in the start ..

Answer (score 1):

Outside of any class declaration or implementation,

```
int ran;
```

defines a variable named `ran` of type `int`, no matter whether that line is in a `.h`, `.c` or `.m` file. Usually this is an error to put it in a `.h`, because if more than one file includes this `.h`, the variable gets defined twice or more.

```
extern int ran;
```

specifies that a variable named `ran` of type `int` has been defined elsewhere and that the linker should be able to find it.

Usually, the general structure of declaring global variables in C (and thus in Objective-C) is:

globals.h:

```
extern int ran;
```

global.c:

```
int ran;
```

myWonderfulApp.m:

```
#import "globals.h"
...
ran = 42;
```

If you need a global variable that is not visible from outside a `.m`, use:

```
static int ran;
```

You can still use it from outside if you provide getters and setters, but not if you declare `extern int ran;` where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

case 1,2,3 are global, 4 is not